# Calling the corresponding method based on the generic type interface

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class

`public class Viewer<T extends GL3> implements GLEventListener`

`GL3` is an interface which is extended, in turn, by `GL4`

[`GLEventListener`](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/45cc13c4d68fb3137b741cbc39ea653c15db2f66/src/jogl/classes/com/jogamp/opengl/GLEventListener.java) is an interface that requires you to implements several methods, such as:

`public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable);`

My implementation at the moment is:

```
@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T gl = (T) drawable.getGL();

    caps = new Caps(gl);
}
```

My goal is to instantiate the `Viewer`, based on the available opengl profile

`viewer = new Viewer<GL4>();`

or

`viewer = new Viewer<GL3>();`

so that `T` will be either `GL3` or `GL4` and then automatically the corresponding `caps` constructor (gl3 or gl4) will be called from the Viewer `init`

The problems is the following, when I try to instantiate the `Viewer`, I get:

```
    Redundant type arguments in new expression (use diamond operator instead).
    explicit: Viewer<GL4>
    inferred: Viewer<GL3>
```

but if I write `Viewer<>()` it, obviously, will have no clue which pick up between gl3 and gl4

and indeed, it ends up calling always the gl3 cap constructor.. (I guess because of the bounded generic `T extends GL3`)

If I force `Viewer<GL4>()`, it changes nothing..

So I tried this:

```
    GL3 gl3 = null;
    GL4 gl4 = null;

    caps = new Caps(gl3);
    caps = new Caps(gl4);
```

and it works as planned, first line will call the gl3 caps constructor and second line the gl4 one

How can I make `T` `GL3` or `GL4`?

edit: from some further tests, it looks like if I call

`caps = new Caps(if(true) gl4 : gl3);`

then always the gl3 constructor will be called, but if I type

```
    if (GL4) {
        caps = Caps(gl4);
    } else {
        caps = Caps(gl3);
    }
```

Then the right constructor is executed...

Edit2: each of this `instanceof` will be evaluated as true (opengl profile is gl3)..

```
public class Caps<T extends GL3> {

    public Caps(T gl) {
        if (gl instanceof GL4) {
            System.out.println("gl4");
        }
        if (gl instanceof GL3) {
            System.out.println("gl3");
        }
        if (gl instanceof GL2) {
            System.out.println("gl2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your left hand side in the Viewer variable declaration? I mean, what is the type you have declared for `viewer`

Comment: Sorry, it was the original name, I just cleaned it to make it easier

Comment: Method invocation uses complie-time parameter type, which will be the bounded type `GL3`. I think either your `Caps` class takes a generic type or you'll need to test the instance type and cast explicitly.

Comment: I also think the real problem is that you have a sub interface `GL4` instead of an interface and several implementations, the latter case fits better for generic type, because if you want to call `GL4`'s methods, then your variable should be referenced as `GL4` anyway.

Comment: I updated the question, `Caps` taking generic type isn't working.. the problem is the `gl` interface, it returns always true

Comment: Of course they are all true if the real type is `GL4`, but if it's an instance of `GL3`, the first expression will be false. What do you want to do in `Caps`'s constructor...

Comment: I forgot to say it, the opengl profile was gl3.. I guess then it's a problem with the jogamp library..? `Cap` is only an example. Sometimes gl3 and gl4 needs to have completely separated class (from a base abstract one), sometimes only different methods inside the same class, and sometimes only a different call in the same method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127538/discussion-between-grape-mao-and-elect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better inject GL3 or GL4 in Viewer constructor instead of using a generic type.
The interface that Viewer implements is GLEventListener, right? And you'll need a GL3 or GL4 instance anyway, don't you?
Therefore, declare a constructor

```
public Viewer(GL3 gl) {
    this.gl = gl;
}
```

and then when you need GL4 features (if available) use **instanceof** to conditionally execute casting GL3 to GL4

Comment: Yes (although I have to grab the `gl` object every frame from the `drawable`), I am thinking about doing something similar at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "typical" solution for such type-erasure related problems is good enough here: Change the constructor of Viewer to take a `Class<T>` argument.

Comment: You mean boxing the `gl` object?